# Convert WabApi response array to typed array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a webapi that returns an array like:

```
[
 {"id":1,"name": "name" }
]
```

[image]

When I am doing get

```
http.get<MyType[]>('url')
.subscribe(data => {
  // data = [Object]
})
```

The data is not getting converted in my object. It is stays like `[Object]`. I can access the data like `data[0].id`, `data[0].name` but the official [httpclient](https://angular.io/guide/http#typechecking-the-response) doc saying that I can typecheck the data which is fine. But how would you convert the whole array in to your type in my case `MyType[]` ?

I am using `angular 4.3+` `HttpClient`

Comment: Can you share more of your code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is your question:

> Do I have to access the data like data[0].id, data[0].name ?

Yes you have, because `data` is an array.

Besides, you said:...

> The data is not getting converted in my object. It is stays like
>   [Object]... Any ideas how to convert the response in to MyType[] ?

I'm not sure you understand what a Type System is. TypeScript is a Type System. It plays no role in runtime. By the time you compile TypeScript (which you have to do in order to run it), there's no TypeScript anymore. If you see TypeScript in runtime, that's just a representation so you can make sense of your code. This is called source-maps. In runtime, it's all JavaScript.

That being said, there're no objects being converted from one type to the other in runtime. The only conversion that exists is something like `(foo as any).bar())`, but again, this only exists until you compile so the Type System can know that `foo` has `bar()`.

Your response should already be `MyType[]`. If you see `[Object]` in runtime, that's because Chrome Dev Tools is calling `toString()` on `MyType`, which hasn't been overriden, so it will display `[Object]`.

Comment: just created a new question that actually different version of this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45686553/how-to-map-object-array-to-my-type-array as this one was too generic and not enough specific