# How to map object array to my type array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a class:

```
export class    Stuff {
      id: string;
      namd: string;
    }
```

With `angular < 4.3` I have this call:

```
getStuff(): Observable<Stuff[]> {
    return this.http.get('api-url-here/stuff')
        .map((data: Response) => {
            return data.json()
                .map((item: any) => {
                    return {
                    id: item.id,
                    name: item.name
                };
        });
    })
}
```

With `angular >= 4.3` I changed it to this:

```
getStuff(): Observable<Stuff[]> {
    return this.http.get<Stuff[]>('api-url-here/stuff')
        .map((data: any) => {
            return data
                .map((item: any) => {
                    return {
                    id: item.id,
                    name: item.name
                };
        });
    })
}
```

I am receiving the array of stuff fro my api that looking like that.

```
[
 {"id":1,"name": "name" }
]
```

[image]

As you can see from the code example above I have to `map` the data twice to get my type shape (`Stuff[]`). Is there a better way of doing this with `angular 4.3+` ?

Comment: how does data from API look and what do you want to have in the end?

Comment: Do you mean 4.3? There was no Angular 3.3.

Comment: @Maximus the api data is like `[{"id":1,"name": "name" }]`. I need to return the thing as I am doing inside `getStuff()` just wondering is there any better way than just having `map()..map()` or may be I can have just single `map()` that I didnt figureout.

Comment: so it returns an array of objects, do you need to get only one object? do you use new http client from `common` package?

Comment: @Maximus Yes I am using `@angular/common/http` `HttpClient` in my second example. I need to get all, so I am mapping over. I did map over twice with `@angular/http` as I was getting `data.json()`. Now I do not need that but didn't figure out how to improve my double `map()`

Comment: The first `.map()` is an `Observable` function. The second `.map()` is a normal javascript array function. Same name, but completely different function. What is the question again?

Comment: @CozyAzure just not sure if double `map()` is make any more sense when I am using `HttpClient` as `data.json()` no longer needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using typed response in new `HttpClientModule`, so in first `map` your result is already parsed.

```
getStuff(): Observable<Stuff[]> {
  return this.http.get<Stuff[]>('api-url-here/stuff');
}
```

Should work. And then

```
SomeStaffService.getStuff().subscribe(staff => console.log(staff));
```

Update:

In this case you will be able to handle the errors in two ways. Outside of your service

```
SomeStaffService.getStuff().subscribe(
  staff => console.log(staff),
  (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    if (err.error instanceof Error) {
      console.log("Client-side error occured.");
    } else {
      console.log("Server-side error occured.");
    }
  }
);
```

Or you can subscribe right in your service and catch the error there. Please refer to [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#error-handling)

Comment: It is working btw, BUT how would you `.catch()` an error inside `getStuff()` in that case? as actually I had `map().map().catch()` just didnt put `.catch()` in the example.

Comment: is there any way to have one single `map()` just for a purpose of having `.map().catch()` ? I just didnt figure out how to do that. so keep stuck with `map().map().catch()`

Comment: No. Let me explain. You should not use `map` at all(if you don't want to perform some additional modifications). In previous `HttpClient` `map` was using to process the response. In new one, all response processing is going internal so you should not use not `map` nor `catch` anymore. Handling typed errors in the subscriber is more clean and unambiguous

Comment: @NikolayOsaulenko, the http.get<MyType>() using HttpClient helps, but it still returns an [object array] that contains my expected array: [object array]
 [0...99]
  [0...9]
   0
    fName: bob
    lName: smith. Is there a first() option? The array I want is still nested in an outer array (i.e. [object array]). Thanks!